# AS3: Two actions on one Click event listener

Tags: actionscript-3, function, event-handling

So what i am trying to do is get a menu to pop up on click. Now I only want to use one. So on the first click i would need it to move to x 130. Then on the next click move to x -77. How would I do this? I've tried an if statement but that didn't work out to well for me.

```
function clickMove (e:MouseEvent):void{
    smenu_mc.x = 130;
    if(smenu_mc.x == 130){
        smenu_mc.x = -77;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code. EDIT: the relevant parts.

Comment: You use an if statement that determines if the menu is currently present or not.  Show the code you're using right now that makes the menu come in

Comment: @Fygo there's the if statement hope that helps

Comment: @LDMediaServices just updated it with the if statement i was using

Comment: LDMediaServices has answered you. But just a detail: you cannot be setting something to 130 and then check if it is on 130 and set something else. Of course it will be. :)

Comment: @Fygo Yeah i understood why it was happening still pretty new to as3 so i couldn't figure out a way to make it go back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are currently doing is always setting it to -77.  Because your if statement will always be true: (see comments next to you code)

```
function clickMove (e:MouseEvent):void{
    smenu_mc.x = 130; //you're setting it to 130
    if(smenu_mc.x == 130){ //this will be true, because of the line above...
        smenu_mc.x = -77;
    }
}
```

What you need to do is toggle the value:

```
function clickMove (e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(smenu_mc.x < 130){ //if it's less than 130, then set it to 130, otherwise set it to -77.
        smenu_mc.x = 130;
    }else{
        smenu_mc.x = -77;
    }
}
```

Comment: it comes out but doesn't go back

Comment: Yeah with your code it just comes out but won't go back on the second click.. Just saw your new post trying it out now

Comment: are you setting the `x` value somewhere else? This is about as straightforward as it gets so there would have to some other influence for it not to work.

Comment: nope it works, sorry about that you had something else up before all this that didn't work. But what you have posted does. Thank you for the help

Comment: Oh ok,  I had it as an inline if statement at first but changed it - I didn't proof read it before so I probably just had the numbers switched accidentally.